# How to create a multi-domain app in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I want to create a multi-domain app with Rails and have been wondering about the best approach.

The app will have a set of functionality that will be the same functionality across all domains, so the change in domain will only mean a change in the db used and the styling (and content obviously) but the models and controller will be the same.

The app will use MongoDB as the main storage (Redis for workers and other stuff that not directly relevant to model storage)

My idea is: Once a user signs up, a new record will be created but also a database will be created with the user id. The user model will store the database id (recently created), and the domain the user have just added. A vhost file would be created and the server reloaded.

Once the user visits the app (using the new domain). the app would check the url and find the correct db to use based on url. This would be saved into variable to be used throughout the app.

I imagine have this check to happen on each request.

I would appreciate thoughts and comments on this approach and best way to achieve this.

Comment: You have multiple questions masquerading as a single question. You may want to take a look at this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised?view=comments) (still works for Rails 4). As for switching between different databases, search here, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I've edited so its just one question now.